# Making div background less than 100% width in CSS?

Tags: html, css, background-color, contact-form

I have simple contact form, but I'd like it to have a bit of a background around it. However, simply putting `background-color` doesn't work how I would like it to. The background color is the full width of the page, but I only want it to cover a small area around the contact form. I've put a picture as to something along the lines of what I'd like it to look like. 
[image: Example of what is required]
HTML:

```
<div class="contact">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name"><br>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name"><br>
        <textarea rows="10" placeholder="Type Message"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .contact {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
}

input[type=text] {
    width: 20%; 
    padding: 6[enter image description here][1]px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-radius: 4px; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin-top: 6px; 
    margin-bottom: 16px; 
}

textarea {
    width: 45%; 
    padding: 6px; 
    border: 1px solid #ccc; 
    border-radius: 4px; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    margin-top: 6px; 
    margin-bottom: 16px; 
}

input[type=submit] {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}
```

Comment: As its name indicates, a `background-color` is a color for the (entire) background of an element.

Comment: You could set the width to something like `95%` or `50%`.

Comment: @James Douglas, I tried that first. It works a bit, but then the form is no longer centered, and it messes with the size of the form.

Comment: @JonathonHooks See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45061098/7733026).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about putting everything inside a container and adding some margins?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="contact">
      <form action="/action_page.php">
          ...
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.contact {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    margin: 0px 50px 20px 50px;
}
```

Then you can use the `container` css to adapt it to the context.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do this:

```
form{
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  width:50%;   /* Put the width you want here */
  margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add width attribute to the contact style like:

```
    .contact{
    width: 80%;
    }
```

This will reduce the width. Change the value to suit your design.

If you want to center the div use margin as:

```
.contact {
width: 80%;
margin : 0 auto;
text-align: center;
background-color: #E0E0E0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width to `80%` for example, like this:

`width: 80%;`

and then a `margin: 0 auto;` to center it, and you're done!

```css
.contact {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #E0E0E0;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 20%;
  padding: 6[enter image description here][1]px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

textarea {
  width: 45%;
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

input[type=submit] {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #45a049;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name"><br>
    <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name"><br>
    <textarea rows="10" placeholder="Type Message"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a specific reason for not limiting the contact div size?
If not, that should simply solve your problem...

If you do, you may consider wrap this div with another one, and limit the inner div's width (either you wrap the contact div and limit it, or wrap its content and limit the inner wrapper)